# Passing Authorization in Axios Header Not Working

Tags: javascript, axios, coinbase-api

I am trying to dynamically generate checkout on the Coinbase Commerce API. I am following the documentation [found here](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api/#create-a-checkout) and porting into a javascript website using axios to make requests.

It seems like their setup requires authentication to be passed in the header of the requests, which I am doing but for some reason it is not working correctly. Their example works in curl directly on terminal, but something appears to be busted in my axios code. Could you kindly let me know how I can fix this?

**Working Curl Request**

```
curl https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/checkouts \
     -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H "X-CC-Api-Key: <Your API Key>" \
     -H "X-CC-Version: 2018-03-22" \
     -d '{
         "name": "The Sovereign Individual",
         "description": "Mastering the Transition to the Information Age",
         "local_price": {
             "amount": "100.00",
             "currency": "USD"
         },
       "pricing_type": "fixed_price",
         "requested_info": ["email"]
     }'
```

**Javascript / Axios Script**

```
let amount = 10;
try {

    let options = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-api-key": "<Your API Key>",
            "X-CC-Version": "2018-03-22"
        }
    }

    let data = {
        "name": "US$" + amount + " Credit Refill",
        "description": "Credit refill",
        "local_price": {
            "amount": amount,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "pricing_type": "fixed_price"
    };

    let response = await axios.post('https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/checkouts', data, options);
    console.log(response.data);

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

**Error**

Error 401 / authorization_error

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x-cc-api-key` and not `x-api-key`?

Comment: @casraf yes! Fixed that now getting another issue... their API docs are joke

Comment: got it working... if anyone is struggling you must specify `requested_info` also even if it's empty